# Specify which O.S. to boot into during installation

Tags: system-installation

I want to Install UM 18.04 on 2nd partition. I have 16.04 on my 1st partition.

Is there any way during installation to get it to let ME decide which I want to boot to?

It's frustrating to have to manually edit grub.cfg to make my 16.04 installation the default to boot to.

Comment: you can use `grub-customizer` (if I have understand well your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `grub-customiser`

Instructions to install:

- Open the terminal and type in `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`
- Open it from your launcher or by typing in `grub-customizer`

[image: GenSettings]

As you can see, you can change the default entry in the general settings tab